# Change height and width of view according to scrollview scroll horizontally using auto layout

Tags: swift, swift3, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout

Container View hierarchy:-

- Container View

  - Scrollview

    - view left
    - view center
    - view right
  - FloatingBottomView

I need to change `height` and `width` constrain of FloatingBottomView according to `scrollview` scroll horizontally.

Initial Outlet:-

```
@IBOutlet weak var constantFloatingBottomViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint! // 300
@IBOutlet weak var constantFloatingBottomViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint! // 70

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = self.view.bounds.width
         // view center in scrollview
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     if scrollView.contentOffset.x < self.view.bounds.width {
        // when scrollview move view center to view left, constantFloatingBottomViewWidth and height goes to down at some point  
     }
     else if scrollView.contentOffset.x > self.view.bounds.width {
       // when scrollview move view left to view center, constantFloatingBottomViewWidth & height goes up to same point range while it down and back to original constantFloatingBottomViewWidth and height
     }
}
```

i have tried using this way to get some scale in scrollViewDidScroll method.
scroll quick left to right or vice-versa did not get exactly out-put

```
let scale =  abs(scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.view.bounds.width)
            print("scale:=\(scale)")
```

Comment: Do you want to increase the size of your floating bottom view?

Comment: yes, it has constrain of height and width to increase according to scrollview scroll horizontally and back to identity.

Comment: @HussainShabbir Have you any idea? how can I resolve this problem.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you just want to show your bottom button with respect to scrollview whenever scroll horizontally right or left??

Comment: @HussainShabbir, yes, it just like snapchat camera button animation.

Comment: Without using animation, there is one way you can add the background UIview like you added the button. Now set background view color to transparent and then add your button on background view. In this your button will always visible irrespective of your scrolling.

Comment: And for animation you need to implement some custom animation logic

Comment: @HussainShabbir, have you any custom logic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151337/discussion-between-hitesh-and-hussain-shabbir).

Comment: can you put your expected animation gif image or animation in snapchat here gif file

Comment: @JaydeepVyas in snapchat Home screen there is floating camera button and more other buttons near it, which is animate while scrolling horizontally.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40328265/6028575 like this

Comment: @JaydeepVyas, thanx for this link

Comment: i think that link is not useful to you because that not give the exact animation code if required more help comment here, i have given that link only for understand view

Comment: @JaydeepVyas, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to give button animation like this 
[image]

For this you have nothing to do just add animation to button like follow 
call setupButtonanimation in viewDidLoad

```
 func setupButtonAnimation()
        {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "transform.scale")
            animation.fromValue = 1.0
            animation.toValue = 0.45
            animation.duration = 1.0
            //Set the speed of the layer to 0 so it doesn't animate until we tell it to
            self.btn1.layer.speed = 0.0;
            self.btn1.layer.add(animation, forKey: "transform");
        }
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
        {
            let screenSize = self.view.bounds.size
            if let btn =  self.btn1
            {
                var factor:CGFloat = 1.0
                factor = scrollView.contentOffset.x / screenSize.width
                if factor > 1
                {
                        factor = 2 - factor
                }
                print(factor)
                //This will change the size
                let timeOffset = CFTimeInterval(1-factor)
                btn.layer.timeOffset = timeOffset
               }
        }
```